# How much data is signed during TLS handshakes?

Tags: tls, asymmetric

My general understanding is that in server-only TLS, the connection establishment proceeds like so:

1. Client opens a TCP connection to the server, passing SNI and other data such as supported ciphers/etc.
2. Server sends back its certificate chain to the client.
3. Client checks that the signatures in the chain match and that the root CA exists in its local TLS CA store.
4. Client encrypts some data for Diffie-Hellman key exchange using the server's public key.
5. Diffie-Hellman proceeds and the server/client determine the shared symmetric cipher key.
6. Client and server can begin sending traffic back and forth, encrypted/authenticated with the symmetric key derived in previous steps.

I'm writing some pretty simple benchmarks in Rust to get a general sense of things like key generation, signing, verification on my local machine. I've already got key generation done in my benchmark suite, but I'd like to get a relatively reasonable sense of signing/verification, and in order to do this, I need to know how much data to sign/verify.

Is the size of the data to sign/verify the same size as the key needed for whatever symmetric cipher that is ultimately used? Can I assume 16 bytes for 128-bit ciphers and 32 bytes for 256-bit ciphers?